# How to set user image next to speech bubble

Tags: html, css, speech

I'm unable to set image next to speech bubble. I'm confused should i wrap speech bubble and user image into a relative division or in absolute division?
Someone please clarify this and help me.

For Left Msg :

```
<div class='row'>
<div><img src="goes here"></div>
<div class='left-msg'>Message Goes Here</div>
</div>
```

For Right Msg :

```
<div class='row'>
<div class='right-msg'>Message Goes Here</div>
<div><img src="goes here"></div>
</div>
```

Demo goes here : http://jsfiddle.net/LwbML/2/

The thing i'm trying to achieve : http://oi57.tinypic.com/jpvg4j.jpg

Comment: full screen demo : http://jsfiddle.net/LwbML/2/embedded/result/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LwbML/3/ are you looking for this

Comment: what changes did u do? because i tried the same before with "float"? and it is not working, if i use float:left for left msg.

Comment: well I checnge a bit markup as well switched image and message doest that help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Css

```
img{
    float:right;
    padding-bottom:-10px;
}
```

and

```
.right-msg {
float:left;
}
```

inside right-image check your fiddle

[This Demo Gives the Output which you have given as sample](http://jsfiddle.net/3mLAr/1/)
[image: Output]

Comment: Kindly check back question, i've posted a demo image.

Comment: sure check it now Did You see that its exactly like your sample

Answer (score 0):

Would a floating layout cater to your needs?

A modified row from your jsfiddle would look like this:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='right-msg' style="float:left">Msg</div>
    <div><img style="margin-left:15px;" src="http://dummyimage.com/40x40/000/fff.jpg"/>  </div>
</div>
```

you may [check the result in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LwbML/10/).

Comment: Kindly check back question, i've posted a demo image.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <img class="align-left" src="images/img-31.jpg" alt="image description"/>
    <div class="text">Next block</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <img class="align-right" src="images/img-31.jpg" alt="image description"/>
    <div class="text">Next block</div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.align-left {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
.align-right {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}
.row {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.text {
    background: #7bbcff;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

Comment: i tried ur answer. but it is not much clean. if i change .text css according to speech bubble css it overlaps. Kindly check back question again, i've posted a demo image. I want bubbles with image like that no matter what is browser window size. Please Help !!

Comment: Sorry but I cant get for sure what do you mean - if I understand correctly you need to add in my example .row {margin:0 0 25px;} - it prevent overlapping the next row to previous